# How can I update a protected variable on the abstract class by its derived classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, menu, abstract-class, protected

I would like to define an abstract Menu class, from which all the derived classes can inherit the functions, but i want that all derived classes can update a single protected vector variable on the abstract class.

So far i've tried this piece of code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class Menu
{

    protected:
    vector<int> commonVector;

    public:
    virtual void display() = 0;
    virtual void addNumber(int i) = 0;
    void showVector() {
        for (auto i :commonVector)
        {
            cout << i << endl; 
        }
    }
};


class Menu1 : public Menu
{
    public:
    void display() override
    {
        cout << "That is the first menu" << endl;
    }

    void addNumber(int i) override
    {
    commonVector.push_back(i);
        cout << "number added" << endl;
    }
};

class Menu2 : public Menu
{
    public:
    void display() override
    {
         cout << "That is the second menu" << endl;
    }

    void addNumber(int i) override
    {
    commonVector.push_back(i);
        cout << "number added" << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Menu1 menu1;
    Menu2 menu2;

    menu1.display();
    menu2.display();

    menu1.addNumber(3);
    menu1.addNumber(5);
    menu2.addNumber(3);
    menu2.addNumber(4);

    menu1.showVector();
    
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Problem is that i can indeed update the commonVector variable by its derived classes, but when I tried to display values, using menu.showVector(), I was expecting to see the pushed back values by menu2 as well.
What can i do to make sure all classes can get the values with the modified data by the derived classes?

Comment: A Ferrari is a car and a BMW is a car, but adding a seat into the Ferrari does not add one into the other cars.

What you want is either a static (try to awoid that), or some sort of ObserverClass, which owns references to your menus.

Comment: Make it static, so you only have one vector for your class: `static vector<int> commonVector;`

Comment: An argument could be made that protected data in a base class is a bad code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design seems to be wrong. Note that if you only use `Menu1` class it will still not work as you wish:

```
Menu1 m1;
Menu1 m2;
m1.addNumber(1);
m2.addNumber(2);
// m1 has only 1, m2 has only 2
```

because `m1` and `m2` are different instances.

Instead of "is" relation you probably want "has" relation, or composition instead of inheritance. E.g.: your `Menu1` and `Menu2` can take a reference to `Menu` and update it together using its' public interface.

```
class Menu1 { // Menu2 similar, if you still need it and if it differs from Menu1
 public:
  Menu1(Menu& menu): _menu{menu} {}  // as mentioned in the comments, doesn't need to be explicit
  void addNumber(int i)
  {
    _menu.addNumber(i);  // make Menu::addNumber a public non virtual method
  }
 private:
  Menu& _menu;
};
```

Then in main:

```
Menu m;
Menu1 m1{m};
Menu1 m2{m};
// etc ...
```

Comment: Just FYI, your `Menu1` constructor does not need to be `explicit` since its input parameter does not allow implicit conversions, ie you can't call the constructor with anything that is not already an existing `Menu` object, including temporary `Menu`s.

Answer (score 0):

The comments' suggestion to make it `static` is appealing but will hurt your project in the long run. `static` members variables and functions are hard to maintain and offer little testability and mockability.

The right way here is to add a `MenuDirectory` class. Each menu can have an optional `MenuDirectory`. In your derived `Menu1` and `menu2`, you check if the base `Menu` has a `MenuDirectory`. If it does you call `addNumber` on it. When the base `Menu` need to check all the option, it queries its `MenuDirectory`.

Comment: You should include an example to demonstrate what you have described.